# WriteValueAsString Jackson showing additionalPorperties As Concrete Field

Tags: java, json, jackson

```
 @JsonInclude(NON_NULL)   
 Class Test{
  @JsonProperty("n_name")  
  String name;

  @JsonIgnore
private Map<String,Object> additionalProperties= new HashMap<>();
   
     /*Name Setter and Getter*/
     /*additionalProperties setter and getter*/

}
Test test = new Test();
test.setName("Test")
test.setAdditionalProperty("testKey","testKey");
OBJECT_MAPPER.writeValueAsString(test);
```

Expectation is

```
{"n_name":"Test", "additionalProperties":{"testKey":"testKey"}}
```

but it is ignoring the additionalProperties and showing testKey as concrete Field.

```
{"n_name":"Test", "testKey":"testKey"}
```

How to get the additionalProperties in Jackson,if I use Gson it works fine

Comment: The code that you showed doesn't match in the type of `additionalProperties`.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I have changed the code this is just a representation, let me know if still has issues